# Electron, IPC communication seems to not be working

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I've followed pretty much everything I could find on Electron, and I cannot seem to add an event listener to a button in my `index.html`.

Upon my button being clicked, I simply want `"something"` to print to the terminal. So I added an event listener to the button DOM element for clicks that will use IPC to communicate with `main.js` and, ideally, print to the terminal.

I've download the [Electron Quick Start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) and have only made these few changes:

**index.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>My Bot</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to Your Bot!</h1>
    <p>To toggle wether the bot is on or not, click the button below: </p>
    <button id="botButton">Turn Bot On</button>

    <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**renderer.js:**

```js
var ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

var botButton = document.getElementById('botButton');
botButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    ipc.once('actionReply', function(event, response){
        processResponse(response);
    })
    ipc.send('invokeAction', 'someData');
});
```

And I've added the following to the bottom of `main.js`:

```js
var ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;

ipc.on('invokeAction', function(event, data){
    console.log("something");
    var result = processData(data);
    event.sender.send('actionReply', result);
});
```

Is my understanding of the relationship between these files screwed up? Am I simply taking an incorrect route to adding an event listener to my button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like an idiot. Upon opening the developer tools in my Electron app, I see the console prints

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at renderer.js:8"

So obviously, node.js is not integrated into renderer.js by default. A simple google search lands me on this page: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17241

It seems that updating

```js
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}
```

to:

```js
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}
```

fixes the issue.

**Moral of the story:** the terminal won't tell you everything when working with Electron. Especially when writing code to a renderer, you should be checking the console in the app's developer tools as well!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to that, you may register the necessary ipc methods to a global variable, like window, in your preload script. Enabling node integration will cause a security issue as described [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/security.md#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content). This way, you are only exposing the essential functionality to the page.

Below, you can see an alternative approach that will work with node integration is disabled.

```js
// preload.js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

window.bridge = {}
window.bridge.handleClickAction = () => {
  ipcRenderer.once('actionReply', (event, data) => {
    window.bridge.processResponse(data)
  })
  ipcRenderer.send('invokeAction', 'someData')
}

// renderer.js
// Register window.bridge.processResponse method
window.bridge.processResponse = data => {
  // Process response
}
const botButton = document.getElementById('botButton')
botButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.bridge.handleClickAction()
})
```